# ASP.NET Razor syntax highlighting for Notepad++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, razor, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

How do I go about supporting syntax highlighting for ASP.NET Razor (.cshtml files) in the Notepad++ Windows application?

I believe the correct way is to use User-Defined Language import files, but was getting a bit overwhelmed in this endeavor.

I found the list of current Notepad++ language files at the URL below, but the one I am looking for is not available from this selection.
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=User_Defined_Language_Files

Before you ask, I use Visual Studio 2012 for most of my development tasks, but sometimes VS is being a pain and find it quicker to do some edits in Notepad++, thus why I am looking for the syntax highlighting rules.

Comment: Consider creating lexer for Razor for another editor, SynWrite. It may have more rules, then Notepad++ syntax xml file.

Comment: SynWrite looks very interesting and with a ton of features. I'm surprised I have not heard of this program before. I suppose there are a lot of unsung applications out there in the open source community.

Comment: @RProgram Thanks for sharing about SynWrite.It must be useful and I'll give it a try.

Comment: I don't see why this was closed - it's a perfectly valid question, and needs an answer.  Where is the syntax highlighting for Notepad++ for Razor?  How is that not a valid question?  F'ing moderators don't seem to be actual programmers.

Comment: If you want a nice text editor for razor, try Microsoft VS Code. Has really nice syntax highlighting. Since Microsoft developed C# and Razor, it's way easier to use their tools

Comment: @KolobCanyon, it's nice that you mention that editor. That has been my editor of choice now for a while now. I still use Notepad++ for simple text editing.

Comment: @NeilMonroe I do the same thing

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that there **isn't** any cshtml syntax highlighter available yet.

If you still want to use Notepad++ though, you could try to find a *similar* language (don't have any tips to give you on this matter), check if its syntax highlighter gives acceptable results (you can check them one by one from the Language menu, and you could try also some User Defined from your link), and if you are happy enough with a language then go to Settings > Style Configurator > Choose your language > add the `cshtml` extension in the "User ext." textbox.

PS. unrelated to Razor, but this might interest you http://www.shilony.net/2012/09/02/notepad-visual-studio-theme/

Answer (score 5):

I do not know of any razor syntax highlighter, but I find that xml highlighting at least visually separates between the html and razor code which is enough for my needs.  I too like using np++ for some smaller edits.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that starts up quicker than VS and offers syntax highlighting and some Intellisense for Razor, you should look at WebMatrix.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Comment: VisualStudio Code might be a decent choice also. https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: @BradleyUffner Indeed. It wasn't available at the time of the original post and WebMatrix is not longer being actively developed so using Visual Studio Code is a better recommendation currently.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I somehow missed that I was looking at an old (ancient) post.